# Read string from index 1 in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, scanf

I'm trying to use string by char array from index 1.

```
char a[100];
scanf("%s", a+1);
```

I thought it will work well, but it didn't work. What is wrong?

How can I skip index 0 and read string from index 1?

Comment: `but it didn't work`. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @DeiDei I cannot read string for `a+1`

Comment: And how did it not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*but it didn't work. What is wrong?*  Nothing wrong in scanning but you might printing `a`,  initialize the char array first.

```
int main(void) {
        char a[100] = { 0 }; /* initilize with 0 to avoid printing junk data */
        scanf("%s", a+1);
        printf("[%s]\n",a);/* nothing it prints bcz you putted data in a+1 */
        printf("[%s]\n",a+1); /* it prints what you scanned in a+1 */
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I got it, I didn't use a+1, I used a. Thx